# Router's childs not loading

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular7

I'm currently building a dashboard which has a fixed menu,
but the content is dynamic.

What I'm trying to achieve is, having my content component load in other components when I change my URL.

So: dashboard/home should get the dashboard's home component
dashboard/links should load the dashboard's link component etc.

This is my router:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomepageComponent },
  { path: 'link/:trackId', component: LinkComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, 
    children: [
      { path: '', component: DashboardContentHomeComponent, outlet:   'dashboardcontent'},
      { path: 'links', component: DashboardContentLinksComponent, outlet:   'dashboardcontent'}
    ]
  },  
  { path: '*', redirectTo: ''},
];
```

Now my Dashboard component looks as follows:

```
<div class="dashboard-holder">
  <app-login *ngIf="!authService.afAuth.auth.currentUser"></app-login>
  <app-dashboard-menu *ngIf="authService.afAuth.user | async" class="dashboard-menu"></app-dashboard-menu>
  <app-dashboard-content *ngIf="authService.afAuth.user | async" class="dashboard-content"></app-dashboard-content>
</div>
```

And the dashboard-content component looks as follows:

```
<router-outlet name="dashboardcontent"></router-outlet>
```

Now to the problem:
When going to "URL"/dashboard the DashboardContentHomeComponent loads correctly!

[image: HomeComponent Working]

But when navigating to "URL"/dashboard/links I get the following error:

[image: LinkComponentError]

I literally don't get what I'm doing wrong, and I've been working on this seemingly very easy feature for 3 hours now...

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You shouldn't use named outlets, they will just screw you over..

Comment: @Chrillewoodz What would you recommend then?

Comment: Why don't you just remove the name?

Comment: @NguyenPhongThien That doesn't fix anything...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a structure like:

```
dashboard <-- have a guard against unauthed users
  links
login <-- have the guard redirect to login
```

Start off by putting a `router-outlet` in your `AppComponent` template.

Then change your template in `DashboardModule` to:

```
<app-dashboard-menu class="dashboard-menu"></app-dashboard-menu>

<div class="dashboard-holder">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div
```

Then I would have a **root** (`AppRoutingModule`) route config like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'dashboard' },
  { path: 'dashboard': loadChildren: './routes/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'},
  { path: 'login': loadChildren: './routes/login/login.module#LoginModule'},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard'}
];
```

Then for each feature you want in the dashboard you will create feature modules and have them as children of the `DashboardModule`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: DashboardComponent, 
    children: [
      { path: 'links', loadChildren: './routes/links.module#LinksModule'},
    ]
  }
];
```

As you can see this drastically improves the simplicity and scalability of your app and removes the need for named outlets. Making it a lot easier to handle navigations in your app. I hope this helps.

Comment: I understand your improvements, however, this was something I wanted to do for my refactor too. Nevertheless, this doesn't add anything to my question.

We can see the logic works because the Content home component, which is only shown when logged in WORKS that's the child with path: ' ' as displayed on the screenshot. However 'links' Doesn't work. And my only question. how do I get 'links' to work, if ' ' works too...